# Where can I find Slam Dunk English dubbed episodes legally?

Tags: slam-dunk

Anyone watches Slam Dunk Anime? It's a basketball anime and I wish to know where can I find English dubbed episodes of this anime. Many thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you're at, you'll need to find your local licensor. In North America, it's currently licensed by FUnimation, and you can watch it online at Crunchyroll or ANN Video, but I think those are both subtitled. If you want the English dub you'll have to find the DVD's. I know at least [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000787ZP8) still lists the English dub DVD's.